# Failed to successfully validate kops cluster state

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops, jenkins-x

I am using this command to try and get a jenkins-x cluster set up and running :

```
jx create cluster aws --ng
```

I've also tried :

```
jx create cluster aws
```

the output looks like this :

```
Waiting to for a valid kops cluster state...
WARNING: retrying after error: exit status 2
error: Failed to successfully validate kops cluster state: after 25 attempts, last error: exit status 2
```

All help appreciated.

Comment: What this command gives you output? `kops validate cluster --name ${KOPS_CLUSTER_NAME}`

Comment: I get nothing back for that, but I did discover some extra logging that I hadn't noticed, while trying to create the cluser... "error: creating the system vault: creating vault: Missing S3 bucket flag"

Comment: and did you configure `kops` account for your aws before running this `jx create cluster aws` https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/aws.md?

Answer (score 0):

Try the kops validate cluster command as shown below

```sh
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<YOUR_KEY_HERE> AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<YOUR_SECRET_KEY_HERE> kops validate cluster --wait 10m --state="s3://<YOUR_S3_BUCKET_NAME_HERE>" --name=<YOUR_CLUSTER_NAME_HERE>
```